# Norton Antivirus blocks JVisualVM Profiler

Tags: java, norton-antivirus

I'm going to contact Windows support and my Norton antivirus provider tomorrow, but I'd like some help if anyone else has experienced a similar issue.

I'm using JVisualVM my first time today in an attempt to profile a program that I wrote. When I started the application, I was prompted by Windows 7 to let this application only communicate over home networks or on public networks.

I chose Home Networks only. However, after I select either the CPU option or Memory option available from the profiler tab for my currently running program, I get a message from Norton Antivirus saying: IPS Alert Name: Web Attack: JRE RMI Serialize Object CVE-2010-0094. "Network traffic from localhost matches the signature of a known attack." The 'attack' originated from java.exe.

Is my selection to only communicate over home networks responsible, or do I just need to add a special exception to norton? I'm assuming that this is a false positive, but is there a way to be sure?

Comment: You can get things called 'false positives'

Comment: I get the same exception, but I have yet to find a way to add this exception to Norton.